# Добавление объектов в вектор

Tags: c++, ооп

```
Patient Registry::NewPatient() {
 
    Patient newPatient;
 
    string name;
    string surname;
    string phone;
    int age;
 
    cout << "Введіть ім'я пацієнта:" << endl;
    cout << "➡ ";
    getline(cin, name);
 
    while (name.find_first_of("\n\t ") != string::npos || name.find_first_of("0123456789") != string::npos ||
           name.empty()) {
 
        cout << "Введене ім'я містить пробіли, цифри або інші неприпустимі символи!" << endl;
        cout << "Введіть ім'я пацієнта:" << endl;
        cout << "➡ ";
        getline(cin, name);
    }
 
    newPatient.SetName(name);
 
    cout << "Введіть фамілію пацієнта:" << endl;
    cout << "➡ ";
    getline(cin, surname);
 
    while (surname.find_first_of("\n\t ") != string::npos || surname.find_first_of("0123456789") != string::npos ||
           surname.empty()) {
 
        cout << "Введена фамілія містить пробіли, цифри або інші неприпустимі символи!" << endl;
        cout << "Введіть фамілію пацієнта:" << endl;
        cout << "➡ ";
        getline(cin, surname);
    }
 
    newPatient.SetSurname(surname);
 
    cout << "Введіть вік пацієнта:" << endl;
    cout << "➡ ";
    cin >> age;
    newPatient.SetAge(age);
 
    cout << "Введіть номер телефону пацієнта:" << endl;
    cout << "➡ ";
    getline(cin, phone);
 
    while (phone.find_first_of("\n\t ") != string::npos || phone.empty()) {
 
        cout << "Введений номер телефона містить пробіли або інші неприпустимі символи!" << endl;
        cout << "Введіть номер телефону:" << endl;
        cout << "➡ ";
        getline(cin, phone);
    }
 
    newPatient.SetPhone(phone);
 
    return newPatient;
}
 
 
void Registry::AddPatient() {
 
    patients.push_back(NewPatient());
    numberOfPatients++;
}
```

Всем привет, такой вопрос: надо реализовать метод добавления объектов в вектор. Как лучше сделать, оставить так как есть, или же сделать так чтобы метод `NewPatient()` принимал в себя аргументы `name, surname, age, phone...` и перенести ввод пользователя и проверки на правильность введенных данных куда то в другое место, например в меню на `switch()` в `main()?`

Comment: Если так стоит вопрос, то конечно лучше оставить так, как есть, чем переносить ввод в `main()`. Возможно имеет смысл циклы с проверкой ввода на корректность вынести в отдельную маленькую функцию и вызывать её из этого метода.

Comment: Дело вкуса :) Я бы сделал функцию ввода и проверки (чтоб при неверном вводе перезапросить) отдельно, функцию добавления в вектор — отдельно...

Comment: Спасибо, @Harry вы написали что можно сделать функцию ввода и проверки отдельно, это мне надо будет например сделать 3 функции для ввода имени, фамилии, возраста?

Comment: Думаю, что делить не стоит. Можно делать отдельные функции для ввода строки и для ввода числа отдельно, но не такой уж огромный у вас ввод, чтоб его делить на куски. Но, как сказал @Harry, дело вкуса :) Кстати, можно все вводить оддной строкой, даже если фамилия из двух слов, например, добавляя какой-то разделитель, которого в фамилии и имени быть не может.